# Updating a variable in jQuery script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am currently building a dynamic form, using a bit of HTML, PHP and jQuery. This form contains a drop down select field (with the tag name) and two input boxes named tag_text_color and tag_background_color.

When you select a tag in the select field, a bit of jQuery will fill the boxes tag_text_color and tag_background_color with the current database value.

Before that, I have a form which allow the user to add a tag in the database. My problem occurs when I right before adding a tag in the database.

Here is the code for adding a tag :

```
        <form id="form_addtag" method="post" name="form_addtag" action="add_tag.php">
                <legend>Add a tag</legend>
                <input type="text" name="tag_name" id="tag_name" class="text" size="30" placeholder="Tag Name" />
                <input type="text" name="tag_text_color" id="tag_text_color" class="text" size="6" placeholder="#ffffff"/>
                <input type="text" name="tag_bg_color" id="tag_bg_color" class="text" size="6" placeholder="#000000" />
                <button type="submit" id="button_save_tag">Add</button>
        </form>
```

and the jQuery corresponding function :

```
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
        $("#form_addtag").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "add_tag.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#form_addtag").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        });
        $('#form_addtag')[0].reset();
        $("#form_edittag").load("demo.php #form_edittag")
    });
```

Adding a tag works fine, and it reloads perfectly the form to edit a tag. However if in this block I am selecting the new tag, it is not loaded yet by jQuery

HTML to edit a tag :

```
        <form id="form_edittag" method="post" name="form_edittag" action="edit_tag.php">
            <legend>Edit a tag</legend>
            <select id="select_edittag">

                <?php
                $tags = get_tags();
                $numberOfTags = sizeof($tags);
                var_dump($numberOfTags);
                var_dump($tags);
                foreach ($tags as $line)
                {
                    echo("<option value='".$line["name"]."''>".$line["name"]."</option>");
                }
                    //print("<option value='". $tags[ $j ]["name"]."'>".$tags[ $j ]["name"]."</option>");
            ?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="tag_text_color_edit" id="tag_text_color_edit" class="text" size="6" />
            <input type="text" name="tag_bg_color_edit" id="tag_bg_color_edit" class="text" size="6" />
            <button type="submit" id="button_edit_tag">Edit</button>
            <button type="submit" id="button_delete_tag">Delete</button>
        </form>
```

Corresponding jQuery :

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( document ).on( "change", "select#select_edittag", function()
        {
            var name = $("#select_edittag").val();
            var tags = <?php echo json_encode(get_tags()); ?>;
            $("#tag_text_color_edit").val(tags[name]["text_color"]);
            $("#tag_bg_color_edit").val(tags[name]["background_color"]);
        });
    });
```

The function get_tags() will return an array with all the tags in the database.

I was thinking that each time I select a new item in my select "select_edittag" it would run the script, and update the tags variable with the lastest content from the function get_tags(). It does not sadly.

Any idea ? If you want a live demo I can host something like that

Answer (score 0):

No.

PHP is running once, when loading the page. You must repopulate 'tags' via ajax. Check: [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: From what I can read in getJSON, it would mean that I have to create a new, different page with the only goal would be to give me the tags in the database ? Is there no other way like using a global variable I update after adding a tag ? I am not really fond of the first idea to be honest